# Set focus back (make cursor blinking on) to UITextView after setting html formatted text

Tags: ios

I have implemented email like application which sends some data to email provided in one text view. For this I have done following:
On each character typed on `UITextView` I prepare criteria string and open one `UITableViewController` in Popover just below textView. `TableViewController` display filtered data from prepopulated data source. Now when user select email from `TableViewController` then that name is passed to parent main view controler which holds both UITextView and Popover for `UITableView` controller. Wehn main view receives email string it will append that text to `UITextView`. My problem is if I set simple text by appending email to current text and call `becomeFirstResponder` on `UITextView` then it will show cursor blinking. But if I set HTML string using `UITextView setValue:forKey` method whith key value "**ContentToHTMLString**" then cursor is not blinking on end of text.If I click on UITextView again then only it shows cursor.

Please give your suggestions/input on this problem. Please note that before setting text to `UITextView` I dismiss popover controller which holds UITableView Controller.

Here I have added two methods which are called when user select email id form UITableView. Let me know if more detail is required. Please note that I cannot share full code here.

```
    -(NSString*) GetHTMLStringFromString:(NSString*)text
{
    NSString *htmlTag = @"<html>";
    NSString *htmlEndTag = @"</html>";
    NSString *aHrefTag = @"<a href=\"\">";
    NSString *aHrefTagEnd = @"</a>";
    NSString *finalHtmlString = htmlTag;
    NSArray *stringChunks = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    for(NSUInteger index = 0; index < stringChunks.count -1;index++)
    {
        finalHtmlString = [finalHtmlString stringByAppendingString:aHrefTag];
        finalHtmlString = [finalHtmlString stringByAppendingString:[stringChunks objectAtIndex:index]];
        finalHtmlString = [finalHtmlString stringByAppendingString:aHrefTagEnd];
        finalHtmlString = [finalHtmlString stringByAppendingString:@";"];
    }
    finalHtmlString = [finalHtmlString stringByAppendingString:htmlTag];
    NSLog(@"\n\nFinal Html String: %@ \n\n",finalHtmlString);
    return finalHtmlString;
}

-(void)HandleUserNameSelected:(NSString*)name
{
    NSLog (@" %s Selected Name: %@\n",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,name);
    NSString *completeString = self.textView.text;
    //NSArray *namesArray= [completeString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
    NSString *userName = @"";
    NSLog(@"Calling FindCriteria from %s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    userName  = [self FindCriteriaFromString:completeString];
    //NSLog(@"Last username:%@",userName);
    NSRange selectionRange = [completeString rangeOfString:userName options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    //NSRange endselectionRange = [completeString rangeOfString:completeString options:NSBackwardsSearch];
    //NSLog(@" start pos:%d   end pos:%d",selectionRange.location,endselectionRange.length);
    //textView.selectedRange = selectionRange;
    //UITextPosition *start = [textView positionFromPosition:textView.beginningOfDocument offset:selectionRange.location-1];
    //UITextPosition *end = [textView positionFromPosition:textView.beginningOfDocument offset:endselectionRange.length];
    //UITextRange *range = [textView textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end];

    NSLog(@"\n\n Total Length %d selction range location %d and length %d \n \n",completeString.length,selectionRange.location,selectionRange.length);
    if((selectionRange.location + selectionRange.length +1) > completeString.length)
    {
        completeString = [completeString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:selectionRange withString:[name stringByAppendingString:@";"]];
    }
    else
    {
        completeString = [completeString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:selectionRange withString:name];
    }
    NSString *htmlStr = [self GetHTMLStringFromString:completeString];
    //htmlStr = [htmlStr stringByAppendingString:@" abc"];
    if(self.isSelectionListOpened)
    {
        [self.popController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
        self.isSelectionListOpened = NO;
    }
    //self.textView.editable = YES;
   // [self.view becomeFirstResponder];
    //self.textView.text = [self.textView.text stringByAppendingString:@""];
    [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
    self.textView.editable = YES;
    //NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><a href=\"\">%@</a></html>", htmlStr];
    [self.textView setValue:htmlStr forKey:@"ContentToHTMLString"];
    [self.view becomeFirstResponder];
    //self.textView.text = [self.textView.text stringByAppendingString:@""];
    [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
    self.textView.editable = YES;
   // self.textView.text = completeString;





}
```

Comment: Hi can you share some part of the code to see what is going wrong.

Comment: I have edited my question with code snippet. Kindly check it